# My Zapdos won't go through Poke Transport. How can I tell if it's legit?

Tags: pokemon-bank

I bought a used copy of Pokemon Black at a video game store today. I booted it up and opened the old save, only to find a Lv 100 shiny Zapdos. I want to transfer it into my newer games, and I got Pokemon Bank and Transporter just for it. However, when I put it into Box One and tried to use Transport, it wouldn't work. It gave me an error screen, saying there were no Pokemon that could be transferred.

I looked up why, but the only useful info I could find was that it wouldn't let through Pokemon that weren't legit. I looked at its stats and move set, and it looked pretty legit. The stats were:

- HP 294
- Attack 209
- Defense 185
- Sp. Atk 256
- Sp. Def 192
- Speed 210,

Moveset: Fly, Drill Peck, Thunder, Rain Dance.

How can I tell if this Zapdos is legit?

Comment: Would a better question be "How do I find out why this pokemon isn't considered legit?"

Comment: There are more aspects to a Pokémon than just the move set and stats. What's its nature? Which Pokéball was it caught with? What's it's Ability? Where did you meet it and at which level? Does it carry any ribbons?

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason it's not accepted by the Poké Transporter is that it's not legit.

Comment: There can be a few false flags. But how about a reference for calculating pokemon legitimacy? I know they exist.